# How to add an i18n dependency to Vue.js' webpack config?

Tags: webpack, vue.js

Having this entry:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      [...]
      }
    },
    {
      test: /\.vue$/,
      loader: 'vue-loader',
      options: vueLoaderConfig
    },
[...]
```

how to add another loader, to have this `vue-i18n-loader` dependency?:

```
module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.vue$/,
      loader: 'vue',
      options: {
        loaders: {
          i18n: '@kazupon/vue-i18n-loader'
        }
      }
    }]
  }
```

This form is failing:

```
  {
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: 'vue-loader',
    options: {
      loaders: {
        vueLoaderConfig,
        i18n: '@kazupon/vue-i18n-loader'
      }
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `i18n: '@kazupon/vue-i18n-loader'` to your `vueLoaderConfig` directly. Or use this:

```
{
  test: /\.vue$/,
  loader: 'vue-loader',
  options: {
    ...vueLoaderConfig,
    loaders: {
       ...vueLoaderConfig.loaders,
       i18n: '@kazupon/vue-i18n-loader'
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: This package has been deprecated in favor of @intlify/vue-i18n-loader